# The meaning of bindings annotation with provider methods

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Now I'm reading Guice's official document and I saw this code.

```
    @Provides @PayPal
  CreditCardProcessor providePayPalCreditCardProcessor(
      @Named("PayPal API key") String apiKey) {
    PayPalCreditCardProcessor processor = new PayPalCreditCardProcessor();
    processor.setApiKey(apiKey);
    return processor;
  }
```

In above code, what does `@PayPal` mean? 
In the page of the document, I understand the meaning of original binding annotations.  We can customize it.  But the usage is like this.

```
@Inject
  public RealBillingService(@PayPal CreditCardProcessor processor,
      TransactionLog transactionLog)
```

In the code, `@PayPal` means this parameter `processor` should be injected the instance indicated by the annotation.
So, what exactly does it mean in the first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the annotation as part of the method's return type. The `@Provides` method you listed does not simply provide a `CreditCardProcessor`, it provides a `@PayPal CreditCardProcessor`. Thus, the method is written `@Provides @PayPal CreditCardProcessor`.

You can then request `@PayPal CreditCardProcessor` as in your second usage, by annotating a parameter in an `@Inject`-annotated method or constructor, or by adding the annotation to an `@Inject`-annotated field. (You can also request it directly from an `Injector` instance by creating a `Key`.)

Answer (score 2):

In the first code, it means "when you find `CreditCardProcessor` annotated with `@Paypal`, use this method as provider".

Concretely, the first one is used to *define* the binding, the second one is used to *request* the binding.

The first one, could be rewritten as a rule in the `configure()` method:

```
protected void configure() {
  PayPalCreditCardProcessor processor = new PayPalCreditCardProcessor();
  processor.setApiKey(apiKey);
  bind(CreditCardProcessor.class).annotatedWith(PayPal.class).toInstance(processor);
}
```

But... you actually can't because then you'd have a singleton. Never it was written that you wanted a singleton.

So the provide methods are the nice tool to allow you making new instances and initializing them before passing them around.